# How to declare the "b variable" as negative?

Tags: integer, blockchain, solidity

I'm trying to declare the value as a negative number, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Contract {
    int8 public a;
    int8 public b;
    int16 public difference = a - -b;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't give a negative number to `uint`, instead you should use int.

What you are looking for:

```
contract Contract {
    int8 public a = 3;
    int8 public b = -3;
    int16 public difference = a - -b;
    //If it did not work, change above line to this:
    //int16 public difference = a - b;
}
```

Comment: I did give it to an int. I've tried "int8 public b = -1;" and that isn't being accepted

Comment: I posted two screenshots of the different outputs. https://imgur.com/a/YoXvzVq

Comment: Updated answer! It was a task that gave you! next time you ask question, if it is a task, mention it and tell what is the task.

Comment: My apologies, I'll make sure to mention that next time! Thank you for the answer "int16 public difference = a - b;" worked.

Comment: Best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the (negative int) value after the equal sign.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    int8 public a; // default value `0`
    int8 public b = -2;
    
    function foo() external pure returns (int256) {
        int256 negative = -100;
        return negative;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might give more insight https://imgur.com/a/YoXvzVq